# regex to separate files that are url

Tags: php, regex

In a JSON file, I want to separate the addresses of that file. To do this I advanced the following regex here.

```
/(api.example.com)([\w.\\\\,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])/i
```

The desired addresses are in [mp3, mp4, JPG, PNG,...] formats.

My json

```
{"head":"<title>\u00a0\u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f 16 \u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06a9\u0628\u06cc\u0631 \u062e\u0632\u0631 - \u0645\u0631\u06a9\u0632\u0622\u0647\u0646<\/title>\n<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex, follow\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:locale\" content=\"fa_IR\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"article\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"\u00a0\u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f 16 \u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06a9\u0628\u06cc\u0631 \u062e\u0632\u0631\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product\/\u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f-16-\u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06a9\u0628\u06cc\u0631-\u062e\u0632\u0631-2\/\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:site_name\" content=\"\u0645\u0631\u06a9\u0632\u0622\u0647\u0646\" \/>\n<meta property=\"article:publisher\" content=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/example\/\" \/>\n<meta property=\"article:modified_time\" content=\"2022-09-11T07:25:03+00:00\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/10\/fa-2.jpg\" \/>\n\t<meta property=\"og:image:width\" content=\"150\" \/>\n\t<meta property=\"og:image:height\" content=\"100\" \/>\n\t<meta property=\"og:image:type\" content=\"image\/jpeg\" \/>\n<meta name=\"twitter:card\" content=\"summary\" \/>\n<meta name=\"twitter:site\" content=\"@example\" \/>\n<meta name=\"twitter:label1\" content=\"\u0642\u06cc\u0645\u062a\" \/>\n\t<meta name=\"twitter:data1\" content=\"15,000&nbsp;&#x062A;&#x0648;&#x0645;&#x0627;&#x0646;\" \/>\n\t<meta name=\"twitter:label2\" content=\"Availability\" \/>\n\t<meta name=\"twitter:data2\" content=\"In stock\" \/>\n<script type=\"application\/ld+json\" class=\"yoast-schema-graph\">{\"@context\":\"https:\/\/schema.org\",\"@graph\":[{\"@type\":\"WebSite\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/#website\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/\",\"name\":\"\u0645\u0631\u06a9\u0632\u0622\u0647\u0646\",\"description\":\"\u0642\u06cc\u0645\u062a \u0622\u0647\u0646 \u0622\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0627\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u062f\u0631 \u0641\u0631\u0648\u0634\u06af\u0627\u0647 \u0622\u0646\u0644\u0627\u06cc\u0646\",\"potentialAction\":[{\"@type\":\"SearchAction\",\"target\":{\"@type\":\"EntryPoint\",\"urlTemplate\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/?s={search_term_string}\"},\"query-input\":\"required name=search_term_string\"}],\"inLanguage\":\"fa-IR\"},{\"@type\":\"ImageObject\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af-16-%d8%a7%d9%85%db%8c%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b1-%d8%ae%d8%b2%d8%b1-2\/#primaryimage\",\"inLanguage\":\"fa-IR\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/10\/fa-2.jpg\",\"contentUrl\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/10\/fa-2.jpg\",\"width\":150,\"height\":100},{\"@type\":\"WebPage\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af-16-%d8%a7%d9%85%db%8c%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b1-%d8%ae%d8%b2%d8%b1-2\/#webpage\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af-16-%d8%a7%d9%85%db%8c%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b1-%d8%ae%d8%b2%d8%b1-2\/\",\"name\":\"\u00a0\u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f 16 \u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06a9\u0628\u06cc\u0631 \u062e\u0632\u0631 - \u0645\u0631\u06a9\u0632\u0622\u0647\u0646\",\"isPartOf\":{\"@id\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/#website\"},\"primaryImageOfPage\":{\"@id\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af-16-%d8%a7%d9%85%db%8c%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b1-%d8%ae%d8%b2%d8%b1-2\/#primaryimage\"},\"datePublished\":\"2020-12-12T09:47:13+00:00\",\"dateModified\":\"2022-09-11T07:25:03+00:00\",\"breadcrumb\":{\"@id\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af-16-%d8%a7%d9%85%db%8c%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b1-%d8%ae%d8%b2%d8%b1-2\/#breadcrumb\"},\"inLanguage\":\"fa-IR\",\"potentialAction\":[{\"@type\":\"ReadAction\",\"target\":[\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af-16-%d8%a7%d9%85%db%8c%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b1-%d8%ae%d8%b2%d8%b1-2\/\"]}]},{\"@type\":\"BreadcrumbList\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af-16-%d8%a7%d9%85%db%8c%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b1-%d8%ae%d8%b2%d8%b1-2\/#breadcrumb\",\"itemListElement\":[{\"@type\":\"ListItem\",\"position\":1,\"name\":\"\u0645\u0631\u06a9\u0632\u0622\u0647\u0646\",\"item\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/\"},{\"@type\":\"ListItem\",\"position\":2,\"name\":\"\u0641\u0631\u0648\u0634\u06af\u0627\u0647\",\"item\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/shop\/\"},{\"@type\":\"ListItem\",\"position\":3,\"name\":\"\u0642\u06cc\u0645\u062a \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f\",\"item\":\"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product-category\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af\/\"},{\"@type\":\"ListItem\",\"position\":4,\"name\":\"\u00a0\u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f 16 \u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06a9\u0628\u06cc\u0631 \u062e\u0632\u0631\"}]}]}<\/script>\n<!-- \/ Yoast SEO Premium plugin. -->","breadcrumbs":[{"url":"https:\/\/api.example.com\/","text":"\u0645\u0631\u06a9\u0632\u0622\u0647\u0646","id":12013},{"url":"https:\/\/api.example.com\/shop\/","text":"\u0641\u0631\u0648\u0634\u06af\u0627\u0647","id":29710},{"url":"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product-category\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af\/","text":"\u0642\u06cc\u0645\u062a \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f","term_id":47},{"url":"https:\/\/api.example.com\/product\/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af-16-%d8%a7%d9%85%db%8c%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b1-%d8%ae%d8%b2%d8%b1-2\/","text":"\u00a0\u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f 16 \u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06a9\u0628\u06cc\u0631 \u062e\u0632\u0631","id":56145}],"id":56145,"title":"\u00a0\u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f 16 \u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06a9\u0628\u06cc\u0631 \u062e\u0632\u0631","sku":"56145","chart_nonce":"f5703a0bef","content":"","unit":"\u06a9\u06cc\u0644\u0648\u06af\u0631\u0645","price":{"price":"15,000","status":"equal","diff":"0","regular_price":"15000","sale_price":"","tax":"1,350","is_dollar":false},"attrs":[{"name":"A4","slug":"pa_analysis","label":"\u0622\u0646\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0632"},{"name":"\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u062e\u0627\u0646\u0647","slug":"pa_carry","label":"\u0645\u062d\u0644 \u0628\u0627\u0631\u06af\u06cc\u0631\u06cc"},{"name":"\u0634\u0627\u062e\u0647 12 \u0645\u062a\u0631\u06cc","slug":"pa_case","label":"\u062d\u0627\u0644\u062a"},{"name":"16","slug":"pa_size","label":"\u0633\u0627\u06cc\u0632"},{"name":"\u0634\u0627\u062e\u0647 \u0622\u062c\u062f\u0627\u0631","slug":"pa_types","label":"\u0646\u0648\u0639"},{"name":"\u06a9\u06cc\u0644\u0648\u06af\u0631\u0645","slug":"pa_unit","label":"\u0648\u0627\u062d\u062f"}],"chart":{"last10":[{"id":"768293","post_id":"56145","time":"1645877287","price":"14405","diff":"up"},{"id":"769402","post_id":"56145","time":"1645949810","price":"14495","diff":"up"},{"id":"774465","post_id":"56145","time":"1646040234","price":"14680","diff":"up"},{"id":"777842","post_id":"56145","time":"1646213538","price":"14540","diff":"down"},{"id":"780795","post_id":"56145","time":"1646292390","price":"14680","diff":"up"},{"id":"781795","post_id":"56145","time":"1646297479","price":"14880","diff":"up"},{"id":"784050","post_id":"56145","time":"1646470495","price":"15045","diff":"up"},{"id":"787424","post_id":"56145","time":"1646555179","price":"15045","diff":"equal"},{"id":"791658","post_id":"56145","time":"1646645789","price":"15000","diff":"down"},{"id":"798720","post_id":"56145","time":"1662881103","price":"15000","diff":"equal"}]},"experts":[{"id":34082,"name":"\u0645\u0631\u062c\u0627\u0646 \u0628\u0627\u0642\u0631\u067e\u0648\u0631","phone":"9138139075","whatsapp":"+989138139075","telegram":"bagherpour_example","internal":"102-103","position":"\u0645\u0634\u0627\u0648\u0631 \u0641\u0631\u0648\u0634 \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f","slug":"\u0645\u0631\u062c\u0627\u0646-\u0628\u0627\u0642\u0631\u067e\u0648\u0631","thumb":"https:\/\/api.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/08\/bagherpour-176x261.jpg","cat":{"term_id":3777,"name":"\u0648\u0627\u062d\u062f \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f \u0648 \u0635\u0646\u0627\u06cc\u0639 \u0645\u0641\u062a\u0648\u0644\u06cc","slug":"rebar-group","term_group":0,"term_taxonomy_id":3777,"taxonomy":"expert-unit","description":"","parent":0,"count":6,"filter":"raw"}},{"id":71917,"name":"\u0631\u0627\u062d\u0644\u0647 \u0628\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0627\u0646","phone":"9138139708","whatsapp":"+989138139708","telegram":"Bahrami_example","internal":"104-105","position":"\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0634\u0646\u0627\u0633 \u0641\u0631\u0648\u0634 \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f","slug":"\u0631\u0627\u062d\u0644\u0647-\u0628\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0627\u0646","thumb":"https:\/\/api.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/08\/expert-test-12-176x261.png","cat":{"term_id":3777,"name":"\u0648\u0627\u062d\u062f \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f \u0648 \u0635\u0646\u0627\u06cc\u0639 \u0645\u0641\u062a\u0648\u0644\u06cc","slug":"rebar-group","term_group":0,"term_taxonomy_id":3777,"taxonomy":"expert-unit","description":"","parent":0,"count":6,"filter":"raw"}},{"id":37654,"name":"\u0646\u0627\u0647\u06cc\u062f \u0644\u0645\u0648\u0686\u06cc","phone":"9138139056","whatsapp":"+989138139056","telegram":"Lamoochi_example","internal":"118-119","position":"\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0634\u0646\u0627\u0633 \u0641\u0631\u0648\u0634 \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f","slug":"nahid-lamochi","thumb":"https:\/\/api.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/09\/lamochi-166x261.jpg","cat":{"term_id":3777,"name":"\u0648\u0627\u062d\u062f \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f \u0648 \u0635\u0646\u0627\u06cc\u0639 \u0645\u0641\u062a\u0648\u0644\u06cc","slug":"rebar-group","term_group":0,"term_taxonomy_id":3777,"taxonomy":"expert-unit","description":"","parent":0,"count":6,"filter":"raw"}},{"id":37545,"name":"\u0645\u0631\u06cc\u0645 \u0642\u0631\u06cc\u0634\u06cc","phone":"9138139078","whatsapp":"+989138139078","telegram":"Ghoreishei_example","internal":"112-113","position":"\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0634\u0646\u0627\u0633 \u0641\u0631\u0648\u0634","slug":"maryam-ghoreishi","thumb":"https:\/\/api.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/09\/maryam-ghoreishi-166x261.jpg","cat":{"term_id":3777,"name":"\u0648\u0627\u062d\u062f \u0645\u06cc\u0644\u06af\u0631\u062f \u0648 \u0635\u0646\u0627\u06cc\u0639 \u0645\u0641\u062a\u0648\u0644\u06cc","slug":"rebar-group","term_group":0,"term_taxonomy_id":3777,"taxonomy":"expert-unit","description":"","parent":0,"count":6,"filter":"raw"}}],"comments":[{"comment_ID":"3558","comment_post_ID":"56145","comment_author":"0913080****","comment_author_email":"","comment_author_url":"","comment_author_IP":"","comment_date":"1 \u0645\u0627\u0647","comment_date_gmt":"2022-09-11 07:25:03","comment_content":"dfdfdfgdf","comment_karma":"0","comment_approved":"1","comment_agent":"","comment_type":"comment","comment_parent":"0","user_id":"6289","like_count":0,"dislike_count":0,"like_status":null,"dislike_status":null,"nonce":"9e92b2f0c2"}]}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the the json file?

Comment: i inserted my json @Mr.Lister

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse JSON with RegEx - use `json_decode()`. Then read the data by key. In you example here are only breadcrumb and expert image thumbnail urls. So only the expert thumbnails are in the desired format:

```php
$json = json_decode(getJSONString());

$thumbnails = array_map(
  fn($expert) => $expert->thumb,
  $json->experts
);

var_dump($thumbnails);
```

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(73) "https://api.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/bagherpour-176x261.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(77) "https://api.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/expert-test-12-176x261.png"
  [2]=>
  string(70) "https://api.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/lamochi-166x261.jpg"
  [3]=>
  string(79) "https://api.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/maryam-ghoreishi-166x261.jpg"
}
```